# How to read php array with nested curly brases

Tags: php

I came across a situation where i need to echo the content from an `array` as shown below..

```
$array1 = [{"name":"v1"},{"name":"v2":{"k22":"v22"}},{"name":"v3"}];
```

and my code is to echo all the key and values as below

```
foreach ($array1 as $names)
{
   echo $names->name; 
}
```

and my output is as follows...

```
v1
```

so i think `php` unable to parse the `curly braces` inside the `array`.

Comment: That is _not_ a valid php array notation. So the question is: where does that come from? Looks more like sone serialization string to me...

Comment: That's JSON, not an array. Use `json_decode($array1);`

Comment: This array is json formatted. Use `json_decode()`

Comment: what version of PHP are you running? If 5.6+ then it should(!) be able to work with the javascript style array literal notation in which case `json_decode`??

Comment: working example for you:-https://eval.in/609852. BTY your json is missing index in the second part:-  `{"name":"v2":{"k22":"v22"}}` i have added `value` as index in it

Comment: apologize for providing incorrect or incomplete information, actually that is an external  json file and i decoded using json_decode() i could able to read all the information except that is present inside nested curly braces.

Comment: The external json file in question is as shown below ... $json_file1 = file_get_contents('https://restcountries.eu/rest/v1/all');
      // convert the string to a json object
      $jfo1 = json_decode($json_file1);
      $allCountriesArray = $jfo1;